# Wordpress PHP Shortcode if isset pulling through for all shortcodes on page

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, isset

When using this shortcode on page multiple times, every shortcode gets the output of the addpad class and the inline style. How do I do this so only the shortcode that has the attributes will output the code?

```
function block_one_third( $atts, $content = null ) {
   extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'bg' => '',
      'text' => '',
   ), $atts));
   if (isset($bg) || isset($text)){ $style = ' style="background-color:'. $bg .';color:'. $text .'"';}
   if (isset($bg) || isset($text)) { $padit = ' addpad'; }
   return '<div class="one_third'. $padit .'"'. $style .'>' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode('one_third', 'block_one_third');

[one_third]
Block 1 - Should have NO additional class or inline style
[/one_third]
[one_third bg="red"]
Block 2 WITH additional html output
[/one_third]
[one_third_last]
Block 3 - Should have NO additional class or inline style
[/one_third_last]
```

Comment: Do you have a shortcode for `one_third_last`?

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't see this comment. I did just change the last one to  one_third and still having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, `isset($bg)` will return true because in these lines, you specify a default for `$bg` if it isn't set:

```
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
  'bg' => '', // $bg default is '' if it wasn't found
  'text' => '', // $text default is '' if it wasn't found
), $atts));
```

Instead of checking if it is set, check if it equals your default value:

```
if (strcmp($bg,'') == 0 || strcmp($text,'') == 0 ) {
    // Do Something
}
```

Comment: With this change I am still seeing the same result. All three "blocks" are still getting the class addpad.

Comment: @RobertL did you change both the if statements? Are they all still getting the background color / text color styles added?

Comment: Yes I did. The red bg is coming through on just the one but all three have the addpad class. 

`function block_one_third( $atts, $content = null ) {
   extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'bg' => '',
      'text' => '',
   ), $atts));
   if (strcmp($bg,'') == 0 || strcmp($text,'') == 0 ) { $style = ' style="background-color:'. $bg .';color:'. $text .'"';}
   if (strcmp($bg,'') == 0 || strcmp($text,'') == 0 ) { $padit = ' addpad'; }
   return '<div class="one_third'. $padit .'"'. $style .'>' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode('one_third', 'block_one_third');`